# Drop buffers in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I am developing a gstreamer application (plugin) that sinks from a video stream, analyzes each buffer for a certain condition and then if that condition is present passes the buffer to the plugin source. If the condition is not present for a given buffer, the buffer should be dropped and the plugin source should not receive this buffer.

Upon looking through the gstreamer documentation and tutorials as a newcomer to gstreamer, I cannot find a way for my plugin to "drop" a buffer.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do the very same thing. Did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using GstProbe for data buffers and return `GST_PAD_PROBE_DROP` or `GST_PAD_PROBE_HANDLED` when yours conditions are met.

If your plugin is based on `GstBaseTransform`, you should implement your own `transform_frame_ip` or `transform_frame`. If so, you can return `GST_BASE_TRANSFORM_FLOW_DROPPED`:

```
/**
 * GST_BASE_TRANSFORM_FLOW_DROPPED:
 *
 * A #GstFlowReturn that can be returned from transform and transform_ip to
 * indicate that no output buffer was generated.
 */
#define GST_BASE_TRANSFORM_FLOW_DROPPED   GST_FLOW_CUSTOM_SUCCESS
```

Comment: Any idea how to do that in Python? I can't find the constant `GST_BASE_TRANSFORM_FLOW_DROPPED` in the Python API

Comment: I can confirm that in version 1.18.1, if you create a custom element from the videofilter template using the script gst-plugins-bad-1.18.1/tools/gst-element-maker , then, returning GST_BASE_TRANSFORM_FLOW_DROPPED from gst_my_element_transform_frame() gives the desired behavior.

Comment: I missed some nuances in this excellent answer when I first read it. To be clear, if you implement a plugin based on `GstBaseTransform`, then `GstBaseTransform` will manage buffer references and passing the transformed buffer to the downstream `src` pad.  To control passing or dropping data, all your plugin needs to do is implement `transform()` and/or `transform_ip()`, and return either `GST_FLOW_OK` to pass the buffer to the `src` pad, or return `GST_BASE_TRANSFORM_FLOW_DROPPED` to drop the buffer.